# How can I wait for a Rust `Child` process whose stdout has been piped to another?

Tags: process, rust, waitpid

I want to implement `yes | head -n 1` in Rust, properly
connecting pipes and checking exit statuses: i.e., I want to be able to
determine that `yes` exits due to `SIGPIPE` and that `head` completes
normally. The pipe functionality is easy ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=863c8566b3edabdf8aa5a646c10d784a)):

```rust
use std::process;

fn a() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let child_1 = process::Command::new("yes")
        .arg("abracadabra")
        .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;
    let pipe: process::ChildStdout = child_1.stdout.unwrap();
    let child_2 = process::Command::new("head")
        .args(&["-n", "1"])
        .stdin(pipe)
        .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;
    let output = child_2.wait_with_output()?;
    let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
    assert_eq!(result, "abracadabra\n");
    println!("Good from 'a'.");
    Ok(())
}
```

But while we can wait on `child_2` at any point, the declaration of
`pipe` moves `child_1`, and so it’s not clear how to wait on `child_1`.
If we were to simply add `child_1.wait()?` before the `assert_eq!`, we’d
hit a compile-time error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `child_1`
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
8  |     let pipe: process::ChildStdout = child_1.stdout.unwrap();
   |                                      -------------- value moved here
...
15 |     child_1.wait()?;
   |     ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `child_1.stdout` has type `std::option::Option<std::process::ChildStdout>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

We can manage to `wait` with `unsafe` and platform-specific
functionality ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89129137aea93de45154cb4600b45ea6)):

```rust
use std::process;

fn b() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut child_1 = process::Command::new("yes")
        .arg("abracadabra")
        .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;
    use std::os::unix::io::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd};
    let pipe: process::Stdio =
        unsafe { FromRawFd::from_raw_fd(child_1.stdout.as_ref().unwrap().as_raw_fd()) };
    let mut child_2 = process::Command::new("head")
        .args(&["-n", "1"])
        .stdin(pipe)
        .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;
    println!("child_1 exited with: {:?}", child_1.wait().unwrap());
    println!("child_2 exited with: {:?}", child_2.wait().unwrap());
    let mut result_bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    std::io::Read::read_to_end(child_2.stdout.as_mut().unwrap(), &mut result_bytes)?;
    let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&result_bytes);
    assert_eq!(result, "abracadabra\n");
    println!("Good from 'b'.");
    Ok(())
}
```

This prints:

```
child_1 exited with: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(13))
child_2 exited with: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(0))
Good from 'b'.
```

This is good enough for the purposes of this question, but surely there
must be a safe and portable way to do this.

For comparison, here is how I would approach the task in C (without
bothering to capture `child_2`’s output):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FAILIF(e, msg) do { if (e) { perror(msg); return 1; } } while (0)

void describe_child(const char *name, int status) {
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s exited %d\n", name, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s signalled %d\n", name, WTERMSIG(status));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s fate unknown\n", name);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int pipefd[2];
    FAILIF(pipe(pipefd), "pipe");

    pid_t pid_1 = fork();
    FAILIF(pid_1 < 0, "child_1: fork");
    if (!pid_1) {
        FAILIF(dup2(pipefd[1], 1) == -1, "child_1: dup2");
        FAILIF(close(pipefd[0]), "child_1: close pipefd");
        execlp("yes", "yes", "abracadabra", NULL);
        FAILIF(1, "child_1: execlp");
    }

    pid_t pid_2 = fork();
    FAILIF(pid_2 < 0, "child_2: fork");
    if (!pid_2) {
        FAILIF(dup2(pipefd[0], 0) == -1, "child_2: dup2");
        FAILIF(close(pipefd[1]), "child_2: close pipefd");
        execlp("head", "head", "-1", NULL);
        FAILIF(1, "child_2: execlp");
    }

    FAILIF(close(pipefd[0]), "close pipefd[0]");
    FAILIF(close(pipefd[1]), "close pipefd[1]");

    int status_1;
    int status_2;
    FAILIF(waitpid(pid_1, &status_1, 0) == -1, "waitpid(child_1)");
    FAILIF(waitpid(pid_2, &status_2, 0) == -1, "waitpid(child_2)");
    describe_child("child_1", status_1);
    describe_child("child_2", status_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Save to `test.c` and run with `make test && ./test`:

```
abracadabra
child_1 signalled 13
child_2 exited 0
```

Comment: *`make test`* — you have provided no Makefile.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Indeed; it’s a built-in implicit rule. Try it! :-)

Comment: @Stargateur: Shepmaster added that error, not me, but I’ve just edited the post to clarify. No need to get angry.

Comment: Note that it *is* a good idea to include your actual error when asking about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Option::take`:

```
let pipe = child_1.stdout.take().unwrap();

let child_2 = process::Command::new("head")
    .args(&["-n", "1"])
    .stdin(pipe)
    .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()?;

let output = child_2.wait_with_output()?;
child_1.wait()?;
```

See also:

- [How do I move out of a struct field that is an Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031002/155423)
- [Unable to pipe to or from spawned child process more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31576555/155423)
- [How do I read the output of a child process without blocking in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34611742/155423)
- [Reading and writing to a long-running std::process::Child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46873877/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338659/155423)

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the related references! For posterity, fixed Rust Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1800a7ef03ff411bf2a67da233e742b6.

Comment: `no method named  wait found for struct Command in the current scope`

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL you forgot to start the process (e.g. `spawn` in the example above)